# Maven projects - how to read a property that is defined in the pom file of a project that is added as a dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

I am working on a large project that contains many maven projects. We are using Maven 3.3.9.

I want to use a property that is defined in one maven project in another project, but i can't access the property.

The situation is: there is one maven project called "product-packaging", that has a pom file that includes some properties. This maven project only contains a pom file. It is used for generating a package that contains a set of components that are compatible with each other.

There is another maven project called "projectX" that has a dependency on "product-packaging". In "projectX" we want to use a property that is defined in "product-packaging".

I want to add xx-ws-rest as a dependency in projectX, and i want to set the version as xx-ws-rest.version, which is a property that is defined in "product-packaging"

The pom of "product-packaging" looks like:

```
<project ...>
...
    <properties>
        <xx-ws-rest.version>1.6.0</xx-ws-rest.version>
    </properties>
...
</project>
```

The pom of "projectX" looks like:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <product-packaging.version>1.6.0</product-packaging.version>
    </properties>
    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-packaging</artifactId>
                <version>${product-packaging.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.company.product.xx</groupId>
                <artifactId>xx-ws-rest</artifactId>
                <version>${xx-ws-rest.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.product.xx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xx-ws-rest</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        ....
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If i correctly see you seemed to misunderstand the concept of the import scope. This will import the dependencyManagement part of that given pom which defines the different versions of your dependencies. Afterwards you don't need to define the versions another time in the dependency management. You can simply use them by defining the dependencies as you already did. So in the end if you defined the dependency com.company.product.xx:xx-ws-rest in your imported pom you should not define the dependency another time with a property. This will make your import scoped pom (BOM) useless...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. The usual way to define common properties for different projects is to use a parent POM. There, you can define properties and let the different projects inherit from that parent POM - that way, the properties are visible for all child projects.